# Не работает отправка сообщения на почту из формы

Tags: php, html

Имею такую html форму:

```
<form action="post.php" id="form-login" method="POST" class="form-login cf">
                        <div class="name f_left">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="FIRST NAME">
                        </div>
                        <div class="second_name f_left">
                            <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="SECOND NAME">
                        </div>
                        <div class="country f_left">
                            <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="COUNTRY">
                        </div>
                        <div class="phone f_left cf">
                            <input type="text" class="f_left phone__code" name="code" placeholder="380">
                            <input type="text" class="f_left phone__number" name="number" placeholder="PHONE">
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="email__input" placeholder="E-MAIL">
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit f_left">
                            <button name="button" form="form-login" value="Отправить">START NOW!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

И PHP скрипт :

```
<?
// ----------------------------конфигурация-------------------------- //

$adminemail="sn97@inbox.ru";  // e-mail админа


$date=date("d.m.y"); // число.месяц.год

$time=date("H:i"); // часы:минуты:секунды

//$backurl="http://site.ru/index.html";  // На какую страничку переходит после отправки письма

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- //



// Принимаем данные с формы

$name=$_POST['first-name'];

$last_name=$_POST['last-name'];

$country=$_POST['country'];

$code=$_POST['code'];

$number=$_POST['number'];

$email=$_POST['email'];



$msg=$_POST['message'];



// Проверяем валидность e-mail

$c = 1;

if ($c==2)

{

    echo
    "<center>Вернитесь <a 
href='javascript:history.back(1)'><B>назад</B></a>. Вы 
указали неверные данные!";

}

else

{


    $msg=" 

<p>Имя: $name</p> 

<p>Фамилия: $last_name</p>

<p>Страна: $country</p> 


<p>Код страны: $code</p> 

<p>Номер: $number</p> 

<p>E-mail: $email</p> 

";



    // Отправляем письмо админу

    mail("$adminemail", "$date $time Сообщение 
от $name", "$msg");



 //Сохраняем в базу данных

    $f = fopen("message.txt", "a+");

    fwrite($f," \n $date $time Сообщение от $name");

    fwrite($f,"\n $msg ");

    fwrite($f,"\n ---------------");

    fclose($f);



 //Выводим сообщение пользователю

    print "<script language='Javascript'>
<!--
function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 6000);
//--></script>

$msg

<p>Сообщение отправлено! Подождите, сейчас вы будете перенаправлены на главную страницу...</p>";
    exit;

}

?>
```

Пытаюсь настроить форму, что бы она данные, которые я заполнил, отправляла мне на почту. При нажатии кнопки выдает надписи без данных(например: Имя: //пустое поле) и на почту ничего не приходит
Делаю такое в первый раз
Помогите, люди добрые

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причины, почему ты не можешь отправить почту:

1)На локальном сервере не настроен sendmail, либо smtp

2)На удаленном сервере запрещена функция mail()

Если же ты пользуешься локальным сервером, то у тебя должен создаться txt-файл, куда будут заноситься твои письма(код, который ниже текста "//Сохраняем в базу данных" в файле post.php).

MAMP не включает в себя почтовый сервер. Ты можешь использовать Postfix или внешний SMTP-сервер, либо установить себе MAMP PRO.

Ниже представлено описание настроек почты в MAMP PRO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание настройки SMTP для mail.ru: https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp

Comment: Я сам ничего не настраивал. Просто открыл ПхпШторм и оттуда открыл html и отправил форму. И так, сообщения пришли на почту, но поля пустые и пришли они спустя 3 часа. Почему так?

Comment: Какой у вас локальный сервер? Приложите письмо, которое пришло на почту.

Comment: MAMP стоит. <p>Имя: </p> 

<p>Фамилия: </p>

<p>Страна: </p> 


<p>Код страны: </p> 

<p>Номер: </p> 

<p>E-mail: </p>

Comment: Сообщение скорее всего пришло от меня, а не от вас. Установи MAMP PRO, чтобы отправлять сообщения. MAMP не отправляет почту.

Comment: Но я ведь даже не включал в работу мамп, как он его увидел?

Comment: и зачем 214 писем прислал?)

Comment: В коде прописано function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 6000); , тоесть страница будет перезагружаться каждые 6 секунд. Меня не было на рабочем месте около 20 минут и страница успела перезагрузиться 214 раз.

Comment: Ахахаххаа.  Проблему так как решить?Про я поставил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39196/discussion-between---and-gleb-ostrikov).